# TF depth_to_space not same as Torch's PixelShuffle when output channels > 1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I noticed something interesting when trying to port a torch-trained model to tensorflow (TF). When the output channels of a PixelShuffle operation are **greater than one**, the corresponding depth_to_space function in TF is not equivalent (Note: I convert the input to TF to NHWC and the output back to NCHW). I was wondering whether this expected behavior OR there is a misunderstanding?

Specifically,

```
# Torch
torch_out = nn.PixelShuffle(2)(input)
```

and

```
# TF/Keras
input = np.transpose(input, (0, 2, 3, 1)) // Convert to NHWC
keras_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=input.shape[1:])
keras_d2s = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.nn.depth_to_space(x, 2))(input)
...
keras_out = np.transpose(keras_d2s, (0, 3, 1, 2)) // Convert back to NCHW
```

and

```
keras_out != torch_out
```

Here is a testbench:

```
import numpy as np

import torch
import tensorflow as tf

from torch import nn
from tensorflow import keras

class Shuffle(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, s, k, ic):
        super(Shuffle, self).__init__()
        self.shuffle = nn.PixelShuffle(s)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        return self.shuffle(inputs)

def main():
    sz = 4

    h = 3
    w = 3
    k = 3
    ic = 8
    s = 2

    input = np.arange(0, ic * h * w, dtype=np.float32).reshape(ic, h, w)
    input = input[np.newaxis]
    torch_input = torch.from_numpy(input)

    shuffle_model = Shuffle(s, k, ic)
    shuffle_out = shuffle_model(torch_input).detach().numpy()
    print('Shuffle out:', shuffle_out.shape)
    print(shuffle_out)

    input = np.transpose(input, (0, 2, 3, 1))

    keras_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=input.shape[1:])
    keras_d2s = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.nn.depth_to_space(x, s))(keras_input)
    keras_model = keras.Model(keras_input, keras_d2s)
    keras_out = keras_model.predict(input)
    
    keras_out = np.transpose(keras_out, (0, 3, 1, 2))
    
    print('Keras out:', keras_out.shape)
    print(keras_out)
    equal = np.allclose(shuffle_out, keras_out)
    print('Equal?', equal)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Shouldn't your first transpose be `np.transpose(input, (0, 2, 3, 1))`?

Comment: Sorry yes... I mistyped.  Updated now.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the typo fixed though.

Comment: I've added a testbench that produces the issue I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are indeed different. If you want them to match you need to shuffle the channels of one of the inputs. Or if the pixelshuffle/depth_to_space layer follows a convolution layer you can shuffle the channels of the weights of the convolution. Specifically, if `oc` is the number of output channels and `s` is the `block_size` then you need to permute the channels of the convolution's weights in TF using `[i + oc * j for i in range(oc) for j in range(s ** 2)]` (yields something like [0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]).

Answer (score 0):

`PixelShuffle`/`PixelUnshuffle` is not numerically equivalent to `depth_to_space`/`space_to_depth`, unless the upsampled image has a single channel indeed. Otherwise, one would need to rearrange the output channels to get the matching outputs, as stated in the accepted answer.

This is not a bug, but simply a difference between conventions. This is arguably related to the fact that PyTorch is traditionally channels-first (i.e., `NCHW` is the most common tensor layout), while TensorFlow is channels-last (`NHWC`).

I have faced the need of having `depth_to_space`/`space_to_depth` in Torch, so I ended up by publishing the implementation as a PyPi package:

https://github.com/lnstadrum/s2d2s